# Optional Argument for user-defined worksheet dimension function not working

Tags: arguments, option-type

I have two user-defined Excel Functions that work independently, but when I combined them with an Optional Argument, part of it no longer works.

The Functions I am testing are as follows:

- Function PageWidth1()
- Function PageWidth2(MyArea As Range)
- Function PageWidth3(Optional MyArea As Range)

Their code is as follows:

```
Function PageWidth1()

    Dim r As Range
    Application.Volatile

    Set r = Application.Caller.Parent.Range(Application.Caller.Parent.PageSetup.PrintArea)
        Debug.Print r.Width
            PageWidth1 = r.Width

End Function
```

And

```
Function PageWidth2(MyArea As Range)

    Dim r As Range
    Application.Volatile

    Set r = Range(MyArea.Address)
        Debug.Print r.Width
            PageWidth2 = r.Width

End Function
```

And

```
Function PageWidth3(Optional MyArea As Range)

    Dim r As Range
    Application.Volatile

    If Not (IsMissing(MyArea)) Then

        Set r = Range(MyArea.Address)
            Debug.Print r.Width
                PageWidth3 = r.Width

    Else
        Set r = Application.Caller.Parent.Range(Application.Caller.Parent.PageSetup.PrintArea)
            Debug.Print r.Width
                PageWidth3 = r.Width

    End If
End Function
```

= PageWidth1(), PageWidth2(MyRange), and PageWidth3(MyRange) all produce valid results.

= PageWidth3() produces and error.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable, which is a requested range, needed to be defined as a String rather than Range.